# Access items inside Webpack bundle in browser console

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, console.log, web-inspector

I am using Typescript with Webpack (debug build using source maps). I can access Static class files in the sources tab normally. However, the class name itself is undefined at the global scope.

```
class SomeStaticClass {
  public static doSomething() {
     console.log("I just did something!");
  }
}
```

I would like to access / call

```
SomeStaticClass.doSomething()
```

from console in the browser (say Google Chrome Inspector Tools). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a workaround like the following. In the main `exports.tsx` (assuming this is the top level export):

```
import { StaticClassToBeExposed } from '...SomeFile';

if(type of window !== undefined) {
   window.StaticClassToBeExposed = StaticClassToBeExposed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get all files, you can do something like this:

```js
window.SomeStaticClass = require('./path-to-file-with-class').default;
```

Inspired by [workwise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61266593/5411817)

Answer (score -1):

you can call the static method by

```
console.log(SomeStaticClass.doSomething())
```

I managed to make it work refer [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=43#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbAprALmNBLYBhcU0A3gFDTQAOArgEYg7QQbbDQAm8CKaAFlgHYBzABQBKYmXLlg8fhHghkAOhDwRAIgCS0AFZUm7LG0ZJkvAYICE60QG5JAXxJOSMuQuWqRXVMxz5ICCUOH3MhMVEgA) url

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? This shouldn't be the case with Webpack, since it doesn't add packed items into global scope.

Comment: @Sachintha Nayanajith :  This does not work. Only global instances are accessible and apparently static classes (or classes as such) are not part of it.

Comment: @Cerberus I attached a typescript playground link

Comment: @WorkWise We cannot access static properties from an instance of the class. The static properties can only be accessed directly by referencing the class itself.

Comment: @Sachintha Nayanajith  Thanks for the link. I am able to access the static class in the code properly. This will do a console.log once for example. However, I want to be able to debug / call the static class methods dynamically from "browser inspector tools" (eg: ctrl+shift+i in chrome) for debugging purpose.

Comment: @SachinthaNayanajith This will work when TypeScript is used directly, since it will emit the script wich add the defined items to the scope. But with Webpack everything is accessible only inside its own scope, not on global level, so playground is not relevant.

Comment: When typing in the console you lose all type checking so it’s not a good idea to debug your Typescript application this way...